# Any suggestion how to remove error "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" while running Appium.js from Java code?

Tags: node.js, appium, appium-android, appium-ios, appium-java

Any suggestion how to remove error "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" while running Appium.js from Java code?
Trying adding type: "type": "module" in your package.json or the .mjs extension.
when "type": "module" added the new exception came.
node:internal/errors:464
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Ritesh Mittal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\lib\logger' imported from C:\Users\Ritesh Mittal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:416:11)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:932:10)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1044:11)
at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:422:30)
at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:222:40)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Used cjs-to-es6 utility to convert appium.js in appium.mjs. But, js not converted mjs.

//Code

```
AppiumDriverLocalService service;
AppiumServiceBuilder builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
builder.withIPAddress("127.0.0.1");
builder.usingPort(Integer.parseInt("4723"));
builder.withAppiumJS(new File("C:\\Users\\Ritesh Mittal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\lib\\appium.js"));

service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
service.start();
System.out.println("APpium Service Started on: ");
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the built `main.js` file instead of `appium.js`.

Try the following:

```java
builder.withAppiumJS(new File("C:\\Users\\Ritesh Mittal\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\lib\\main.js"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is solved correcting Appium path. It was needed till node_modules\appium